# Is there some piece of code acting the same way as `add_month` do in oracle?

Tags: python, greenplum

Oracle [`add_months`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) function will return the last day of month if you pass the last day of month to it.But in python ,as far as I have known,[relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) cannot return the last day of month.

I cannot import [MonthDelta](https://pythonhosted.org/MonthDelta/#),and I don't know if it works.

For example,`add_months(to_date('20190430','yyyymmdd'),-6)` returns `'20181031'`,

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

date(2019,4,30) - relativedelta(months=6)
# returns 20181030
```

I wonder if there is some function acting exactly as `add_month` do in python or greenplum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one day to the initial last day of the month before subtracting months.
Then you can subtract that day to get the last day of previous month.

```py
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

my_date = datetime.date(2019,4,30)

date_six_months_ago = my_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1) - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=6) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(date_six_months_ago)
```

Outputs:

```
2019-10-31
```

Step by step:

```
2019-04-30 + 1 day = 2019-05-01

2019-05-01 - 6 months = 2018-11-01

2018-11-01 - 1 day = 2018-10-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different answers:

1. Install the Oracle compatibility functions in Greenplum.

   ```
   psql -f /usr/local/greenplum-db/share/postgresql/contrib/orafunc.sql
   ```

And then you can use the add_months() function in Oracle just like you did in Oracle.

2. You can use an interval data type to add a month.

   ```
   your_date_field + interval '1 month'
   ```